# Most efficient way to take run frequency data and convert to valid times

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, datetime, time

This is a somewhat confusing question. Hopefully I can word it in a way that makes sense.

In my sql server 2008 r2 database I have a table called `expectedTimes` that tells how often a task runs with a start and end time. It looks like the below

```
| taskID | startTime | endTime | freq |
|________|___________|_________|______|
|    1   |    08:00  |   13:45 |  30  |
|    2   |    00:00  |   23:59 |  15  |
|    3   |    06:35  |   20:20 |  10  |
|    4   |    08:00  |   09:00 |  5   |
|________|___________|_________|______|
```

I will be running a script every 15 minutes that checks for what tasks were expected to run. What would be the most efficient way to display that at `8:36` the following is returned. The reason I need an efficient way to do this is that there are 1500 rows in the `expecteTimes` table. Having to every 15 minutes multiply out how ever many times to get to the current time seems very resource intensive

```
| taskID | expected |
|________|__________|
|    1   |   08:30  |
|    2   |   08:30  |
|    3   |   08:25  |
|    3   |   08:35  |
|    4   |   08:25  |
|    4   |   08:30  |
|    4   |   08:35  |
```

Comment: How do you measure efficiency?

Comment: I guess I measure efficiency on what would be least intensive on both the webserver (running the php script) as well as the db server. Would making a table that displays ALL the expected run times for all the tasks be best? And then every 15 just checking against that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i wrote this sql - hope to be useful.

```
create table temp
(
  taskID int,
  starttime time,
  EndTime time,
  freq int 
)
insert into temp (taskID,starttime,EndTime,freq)
select 1   ,    '08:00'  ,   '13:45' ,  30  
union all
select 2   ,    '00:00'  ,   '23:59' ,  15  
union all
select 3   ,    '06:35'  ,   '20:20' ,  10  
union all
select 4   ,    '08:00'  ,   '09:00' ,  5   

    Declare @date datetime
    SELECT @date = Getdate() 

    ;with src as (
    SELECT  
    convert(datetime2(0),cast(cast(getdate() as date) as nvarchar)+' '+cast(starttime as nvarchar),102) startDate,
    convert(datetime2(0),cast(cast(getdate() as date) as nvarchar)+' '+cast(Endtime as nvarchar),102) endDate
    ,* FROM    temp
    )

    SELECT 
    case when @date between startDate and endDate then dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,startdate,getdate())/freq+1)*15,startDate)
    else dateadd(d,1,startDate) end as NextRun,
    *
    FROM    src
```

Comment: I might need a little help deciphering what is going on here. I feel super dumb, but what is `;with src as(` and do I replace `FROM src` with `FROM expectedTimes`. That being the source referenced above?

Comment: The "src" is just the name of [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) and you can change it with more appropriate name. And yes this is the name of the source that you are calling in the select statement at the bottom.

Comment: And the `with` statement and the `temp` statement?

Comment: Sorry - i missed one part of my sql statements. Read more about Common Table Expressions.